# Unable to use variable input

Tags: excel, vba, variables

**Background**

As I am trying to run a set of technical indicators on a large number of csv data files, I patched together a 3 macros which was intended to

- Macro 1: RunAnalysis > Open every individual excel file in specific
  folder
- Macro 2: DoWork > Run Macro  Macro 3: IndicatorData > To
  populate the individual csv files opened by Macro 1 with technical
  indicator formulas.

The codes are found below.

**Problem/Issue**

- The problem lies with Macro 3 [Indicator Data]

The value of variable EMAWindow1 which captures a value from the sheet called ControlPanel found in the same Workbook is used selectively by vba when populating column H.

In the first two lines of formulas

```
ActiveSheet.Range("h1") = EMAWindow1 & " Day EMA"
ActiveSheet.Range("h" & EMAWindow1 + 1) = "=average(R[-" & EMAWindow1 - 1 & "]C[-3]:RC[-3])"
```

You will find the macro working perfecting. However

When you reach the third line

```
ActiveSheet.Range("h" & EMAWindow1 + 2 & ":h" & LastRowCheck).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-3]*(2/(EMAWindow1 + 1)) + R[-1]C[0] * (1-(2/(EMAWindow1 + 1)))"
```

For some reason, the value of EMAWindow1 is not used and is treated as a text causing error and resulting in the #NAME? as the formula is unable to calculate with a text inside it.

The subsequent codes encounter the same problem. Anyone faced the same problem before? I have been at this problem for awhile, and I hope for some enlightenment.

---

**Codes**

```
Sub RunAnalysis()

    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Pathname = "C:\Users\gabri_000\Desktop\Trading Data\Stocks - 1 - 100\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.csv")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
        DoWork wb
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
    With wb

        Call IndicatorData

    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub IndicatorData()

Dim LastRowCheck As Long

Dim EMAWindow1, EMAWindow2, EMAWindow3 As Long

Dim Pathname, Filename, FileNameIndex, FinalFileName As String

    'Converting file path into a string
    Pathname = "C:\Users\gabri_000\Desktop\Trading Data\Stocks - 1 - 100\"

    'Full file name
    Filename = Dir(Pathname)

    'Removing the .csv portion of the file name
    FileNameIndex = InStr(1, Filename, ".csv")
    FinalFileName = Left(Filename, FileNameIndex - 1)

    'Selecting Recently Opened File
    Sheets(FinalFileName).Select

    'Counting Number of Rows in the worksheet
    With Worksheets(FinalFileName)
        LastRowCheck = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'EMA Inputs
    'Obtaining data from masterfile
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ControlPanel")

    EMAWindow1 = .Range("EMAWindow1")
    EMAWindow2 = .Range("EMAWindow2")
    EMAWindow3 = .Range("EMAWindow3")

    End With

    'EMA Calcuations
    ActiveSheet.Range("h1") = EMAWindow1 & " Day EMA"
    ActiveSheet.Range("h" & EMAWindow1 + 1) = "=average(R[-" & EMAWindow1 - 1 & "]C[-3]:RC[-3])"
    ActiveSheet.Range("h" & EMAWindow1 + 2 & ":h" & LastRowCheck).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-3]*(2/(EMAWindow1 + 1)) + R[-1]C[0] * (1-(2/(EMAWindow1 + 1)))"

    ActiveSheet.Range("i1") = EMAWindow2 & " Day EMA"
    ActiveSheet.Range("i" & EMAWindow2 + 1) = "=average(R[-" & EMAWindow2 - 1 & "]C[-4]:RC[-4])"
    ActiveSheet.Range("i" & EMAWindow2 + 2 & ":i" & LastRowCheck).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-4]*(2/(EMAWindow2 + 1)) + R[-1]C[0] * (1-(2/(EMAWindow2 + 1)))"

    ActiveSheet.Range("j1") = EMAWindow3 & " Day EMA"
    ActiveSheet.Range("j" & EMAWindow3 + 1) = "=average(R[-" & EMAWindow3 - 1 & "]C[-5]:RC[-5])"
    ActiveSheet.Range("j" & EMAWindow3 + 2 & ":i" & LastRowCheck).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-5]*(2/(EMAWindow3 + 1)) + R[-1]C[0] * (1-(2/(EMAWindow3 + 1)))"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Axel!  I have tried removing the (.FormulaR1C1), the result however still the same. I never had this problem before, any idea what else may be causing the problem

Comment: I had not seen, that EMAWindow1 seems to be a named range. So if this results in #NAME? error, then the name EMAWindow1 is defined for one sheet only, not for the whole workbook, and this sheet is not the ActiveSheet while your code runs. Or the name EMAWindow1 is defined for a completely different workbook (ThisWorkbook vs. ActiveWorkbook while your code runs).

Comment: Yeah the ActiveSheet selected is another one? I am guessing that's why it does not work. Any idea what might solve this problem?

Comment: Check the scope of your defined names. The scope has to be set to workbook. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64

Comment: Thanks Axel! I will check it out